# Unable to have two Bootstrap modals working in the same page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to make two separate buttons for two separate modals in the same page. However, I only got the first modal working and the other second one is only making the background of the page shadowed or dark with no modal appearing.

This is what I am using to do this, I have tried several things and I have played with code a lot and still haven't known what is causing this problem I am facing

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#questionBankModal">
            <li class="fa fa-plus fa-fw"></li> New
        </button>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#testModal">
            <li class="fa fa-plus fa-fw"></li> New
            </button>


<div class="modal fade" id="questionBankModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalLabel1" >
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New Bank</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form action="{{ route('postAddNewQuestionBank') }}" method="POST">

                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Description</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="description" name="description"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add Test">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal fade" id="testModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalLabel2">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="ModalLabel2">New Bank</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form action="{{ route('postAddNewTest') }}" method="POST">

                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Description</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="description" name="description"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add Test">
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: you forget a closing tag </div> at the end of each modal. It should solve the "issue".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your modals are malformed: each one miss a closing `</div>` tag.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#questionBankModal">
     <li class="fa fa-plus fa-fw"></li> New
</button>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#testModal">
    <li class="fa fa-plus fa-fw"></li> New
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="questionBankModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalLabel1" >
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New Bank</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="{{ route('postAddNewQuestionBank') }}" method="POST">

                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Description</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="description" name="description"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add Test">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="testModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ModalLabel2">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="ModalLabel2">New Bank</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="{{ route('postAddNewTest') }}" method="POST">

                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Description</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="description" name="description"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add Test">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting that background shadow darker that means second Modal working fine.
It can be either hiding behind the first Modal or you need to set z-index (Second Modal) properly.
It could be easy if you create fiddle though!